# Laravel Eloquent query unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've found some query result really unexpected.

It's **Laravel 5.2**

We have following entity:

`User` with method:

```
public function roles() : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('timestamp');
}
```

Each `User` can have many roles, so we have also `Role` entity (but it doesn't matter much in my question) and `pivot` table `user_role` with `timestamp` field (and ids of course), because we hold information about time, when `User` achieved specific role.

I want to get all `Users` with theirs last assigned `Role`

When I create query (in `User` context in some repository):

```
$this->with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc');
}])->all();
```

the result will contain `Users` with `Roles` entities inside itself ordered by timestamp - it's ok. But I want to retrieve only **one last role** inside each `User` entity not **all** ordered.

So...

```
$this->with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')->limit(1);
}])->all();
```

And then I retrieve `Users` but only `User` which achieved some `Role` for the very last time contains it! All the other `Users` have their `roles` field containing **empty array**.

Why ordering was performed on each `Users` relation separately, but when I added `limit` it behaved like a global limit for all.

It drives me crazy...

Thanks for advices.

### EDIT

I've created `lastRoles()` method to get all `Roles` ordered desc. But **all**, retrieving **one** is impossible.

```
public function lastRoles() : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(Roles::class)->withPivot('timestamp')->latest('timestamp');
}
```

And for testing:

```
$users = (new User())->with('lastRoles')->get();
```

But now I must iterate over `Users` and invoke `lastRoles()` on each one:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    var_dump($user->lastRoles()->get()->first()->name);
}
```

Then I retrieve names of latest `Roles` assigned to each `User`.

So... There is no way to do it in **one** query? This is the only way?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if you still need a way to grab the latest role only, you might find this link helpful: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Answer (score 0):

When you eager load a relationship with query constraint(s), the query will be run once to load all relationships, not each one individually. This is the expected behavior. Think about it, eager loading exists to turn many queries into one query in order to optimize performance. There is only one query executed, so your `limit` constraint will limit the entire result set, rather than on a per model basis.

To circumvent this, you could try creating another `belongsToMany` method that adds the desired limit constraint. The following code is untested:

```
public function lastRole() : BelongstoMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
                ->withPivot('timestamp')
                ->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                ->limit(1);
}
```

Assuming this works, you can then simply change the relationship method from `roles` to `lastRole` and remove your query constraint:

```
$this->with('lastRole')->all();
```

Comment: Can you imagine that your answer gives me the same result, as I described? Why? I can't understand it now. When I call `lastRole()` on single entities - then it works correctly, but in group query, when I want to retrieve `all()` using `with()` it imposes `limit` in global context, it's a shame...

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you would need a helper function:

```
public function latestRole()
{
 return $this->hasOne(Role::class)->withPivot('timestamp')->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC');
}
```

And then:

```
$this->with('latestRole')->get();
```

Credits to this [awesome article](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/).

Comment: Not sure how this is different from my answer. Also does not answer OP's question.

Comment: It gives all `Roles` ordered descending for every `User`, I want to get only one (the latest) for each one.

Comment: Did retrieve it using `$row->latestRole->somecolumn`? Because it should work, because the hasOne relationship is the key. It should receive only *one* row.

Comment: The code proves it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php

Comment: I am using `BelongsToMany`, I have `many-to-many` relationship.
Can I use `hasOne` when I have `many-to-many` relationship?

Comment: @pavon147 yes, you can. But using the helper function I provided, should return the last row. The hasOne relationship (for only the latest), forces the relationship to return one result, which meets your wishes.

Comment: When I have `hasOne` I get: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withPivot(), so your answer doesn't work. `latest()` doesn't work too. In documentation we have mentioned, that `hasOne` is for `one-to-one`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128489/discussion-between-pavon147-and-jan-willem).